# How do you get a SQL Server Query execution plan in VS Code?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

How do you get SQL Execution Plan in VS code? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: See `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL` and `SET SHOWPLAN_XML` for the plan xml.

Comment: If you want a VSCode like experience you could use Azure Data Studio, which is effectively a fork of VSC. That does have some support for query plans (I use some, as it's functionality is quirky/lacking).

Comment: Azure Data studio is better tool for this. It is build on similar platform as VSCode. Here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you are using version 18 of SSMS you will almost certainly have Azure Data Studio it's part of the install.

Comment: I am using Azure SQL. I like Azure Data Studio, but I do 90% of my work in VS code; it'd be nice to have the visual query plan as an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you do not.

Getting the raw data is not that complicated..

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON
SET STATISTICS XML ON -- The is the recommended option to use
```

But that deos NOT give you the visualization, and that is simply not built into VS Code. An extension WOULD possibly do it - but noone has to my knowledge written that one.

Sorry, sometimes the answer is just "not happening".